# jQuery ui isn't loading

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to implement the tabs widget on a particular page.

- I have both `jquery_update` and `jquery_plugins` modules enabled.
- If I go to `Administration > Reports > Status report` Under jQuery Update, I see `jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.2` are both green and showing as loaded.
- If I type `jQuery.fn.jquery` into the console I see `"1.10.2"`

But the bad news is

- If I try to use `jQuery("#tabs").tabs();`  I get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error
- If I enter any of the following "jQuery.fn.ui","jQuery.ui", "$.fn.ui", "$.ui" into the console:  I get `undefined`
- Having this in my `template.php`:

:

```
 function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
   drupal_add_library('jquery_plugin', 'tabs.min.js');
 }
```

does nothing.

- And finally, checking the heading of the rendered page, I see a call to Google CDN to the minified version of jQuery 1.10.2, but don't see any similar call to grab the jQuery UI library.

Working with Drupal and jQuery is such a nightmare, what else can I check, do, change, to get this working?

Comment: Check the HTML source and verify the jQuery-update module's files are actually being loaded. I recently had an issue that it added files like jquery-ui-ease, and the files were named as jquery.ui.ease. Definitely a bug in the module but I fixed it by moving the files manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme_preprocess_page function use this

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
```

Here is a list of all the libraries for 'system' https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_library/7